# Linq to SQL - SubmitChanges not working

Tags: linq-to-sql

So - I have a MySQL db with one employee table, using Devart Linq to SQL (for MySQL)
It has a primary key in the DataContext,
I can load the gridview,
select a row,
set an instance of Staff = to the ID and Name or the row selected in the gridview
set a Textbox = to Name of Staff
change the textbox and set the object Staff.Name to the textbox.....

but I cant submit the change back to the db!!!!  Probably a stupid thing I'm doing as a newbie.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim db As New MydbContext.MydbDataContext
    Dim bs = New BindingSource
    Dim Staff As New MydbContext.Employee

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ' load employee data from MySQL db in datagrid

        Dim StaffQuery = From s In db.Employees Select s
        bs.DataSource = StaffQuery
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bs

        ' this works fine

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

        'create an instance of the object Staff with the ID and Name from the datagrid
        'is there a better way to do this?

        Staff.EmployeeID = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("EmployeeID").Value
        Staff.Name = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Name").Value
        MsgBox(Staff.EmployeeID & " " & Staff.Name)
        TextBox1.Text = Staff.Name

        'this works fine

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Staff.Name = TextBox1.Text   'edit the Name
        MsgBox(Staff.EmployeeID & " " & Staff.Name)  ' this works - shows new Staff.Name from textbox
        db.SubmitChanges()   ' this fails to make db changes

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to add `db.Staffs.InsertOnSubmit(Staff)`

Where `Staffs` is the name of the collection of `Staff` objects.

However, rather than keep the context and object around all the time, why not just create the new Staff object when the user presses the save button?

Finally, you can call `GetChangeSet()` on your db context to see what changes are pending. This can help you understand when something strange happens.

Comment: No luck - tried all of the above.  InsertOnSubmit' is not a member of 'LinqTest.MydbContext.MydbDataContext

Comment: Where is your call to `InsertOnSubmit()`?

Comment: Private Sub bntSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bntSave.Click

        Dim employee As New MydbContext.Employee
        employee.Name = TextBox1.Text
        MsgBox(employee.EmployeeID & " " & employee.Name)  ' this works - shows new Staff.Name from textbox
        db.SubmitChanges()   ' this fails to make db changes
        MsgBox(db.GetChangeSet().ToString)   'this tells me "Added: 0, Removed: 0, Modified: 0" 

        'db.InsertOnSubmit(Staff)  'ERROR===> InsertOnSubmit' is not a member of 'LinqTest.MydbContext.MydbDataContext

    End Sub

Comment: My bad. I have fixed my answer. You could have edited your question.

Comment: GetChangeSet() tells me "Added: 0, Removed: 0, Modified: 0"

Comment: With the db.Staffs.InsertOnSubmit(Staff) I'm now inserting to the db.  How do I append?  There is a DeleteOnSubmit.  Even thought the Staff object primarykey is set to the record I want to update it creates a new record??

Comment: I need an UpdateOnSubmit - but this doesn't exist?

Comment: If you find a record and change it within the scope of a `DataContext`, `SubmitChanges()` will perform the update automatically.